# Synonym: [virtual-reality]/[vr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I recently found two tags, [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) and [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality). From the excerpts and names, it's quite obvious that they mean the same thing.

I'm leaning towards making [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) the main tag because it has more questions and a better excerpt, but the thing is [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) is a much clearer tag name.

Does anyone have any thoughts on which to use?

Comment: I don't know convention, but I personally think having the fully specified tag, rather than the acronym, makes things clearer.

Comment: Question counts for the curious: VR has 522, virtual-reality has 151.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sniffed around here a bit, and the usage between those two tags was 100% consistent. In fact, a large number of questions were tagged *both* [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) and [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality). The ones that had only one tag or the other were obviously still about virtual reality.

So this is now done. [As suggested by Keiwan et al](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343912), [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) was merged into [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality), and a synonym was created.

I also manually merged the tag wikis, although one of them contained primarily plagiarized content, so I obviously didn't carry that over. The wiki is a little sparse now, so anyone with expertise in this topic area should feel free to go and edit it.

There are still some bad questions in here that need to go. I got rid of a couple that I happened across (including one with an answer that began, *"This is not a suitable question at all. Even thought, I will answer it."*), but I didn't take the time to go through them all systematically. The merge didn't make that task any more difficult, though, as the bad questions weren't localized to either [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) or [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality).

Answer (score 9):

I'd keep the [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) tag and replace its excerpt with the one for [vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) - obviously adjusting it a little bit to something like:

> Virtual Reality (or VR) deals with Human Computer Interaction in
>   immersive Systems. It may also refer to immersive content creation
>   tools suitable for creation of media best viewed within these
>   immersive systems.

Comment: I agree.  I suggest upgrading the [tag:virtual-reality] tag wiki so that it is equivalent to the [tag:vr] tag wiki, and then doing a systematic tag edit on the questions with [tag:vr], changing it to to [tag:virtual-reality], and synonymizing [tag:vr] to [tag:virtual-reality].  (I note that when I typed this comment, there were 584 [tag:vr] questions, and 171 [tag:virtual-reality] questions, with 41 having both tags.  There'll probably be fewer dual-tagged questions by the time you go to look for them.)